# How to zoom around an svg

Tags: svg, d3.js

I have an svg graphic created with javascript and d3.

I want to be able to zoom in on any of the circles when you click on it.

I assumed I could do it by adding a transform on the whole diagram, of:

translate - to move the whole diagram so the chosen circle is in the centre

scale - to expand the diagram so the chosen circle took up the whole space

How wrong I was!

I read up a bit, and tried:

translate - so the origin of the circle was at 0,0

scale - so the radious of the circle was expanded to the size of the svg

translate again - to move the circle back into the centre - the translations scaled by the scale factor

Still didn't work!

Can anyone explain how I could do that?

Code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<style>
  text {
  font: 24px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-anchor: middle;
  pointer-events: none;
}

circle {
  fill: #ccc;
  stroke: black;
}

.node:hover circle {
  fill: orange;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var json = {
 "name": "flare",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "analytics",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "cluster",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "value": 3938},
      {"name": "CommunityStructure", "value": 3812},
      {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "value": 6714},
      {"name": "MergeEdge", "value": 743}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "graph",
     "children": [
      {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "value": 3534},
      {"name": "ShortestPaths", "value": 5914},
      {"name": "SpanningTree", "value": 3416}
     ]
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "animate",
   "children": [
    {"name": "Easing", "value": 17010},
    {"name": "FunctionSequence", "value": 5842},
    {
     "name": "interpolate",
     "children": [
      {"name": "ArrayInterpolator", "value": 1983},
      {"name": "ObjectInterpolator", "value": 1629},
      {"name": "PointInterpolator", "value": 1675},
      {"name": "RectangleInterpolator", "value": 2042}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "ISchedulable", "value": 1041},
    {"name": "Parallel", "value": 5176},
    {"name": "TransitionEvent", "value": 1116},
    {"name": "Tween", "value": 6006}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "query",
   "children": [
    {"name": "AggregateExpression", "value": 1616},
    {"name": "Expression", "value": 5130},
    {"name": "ExpressionIterator", "value": 3617},
    {"name": "Fn", "value": 3240},
    {"name": "If", "value": 2732},
    {"name": "IsA", "value": 2039},
    {"name": "Literal", "value": 1214},
    {"name": "Match", "value": 3748},
    {"name": "Maximum", "value": 843},
    {
     "name": "methods",
     "children": [
      {"name": "add", "value": 593},
      {"name": "where", "value": 299},
      {"name": "xor", "value": 354},
      {"name": "_", "value": 264}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "Minimum", "value": 843},
    {"name": "Not", "value": 1554},
    {"name": "Or", "value": 970},
    {"name": "Query", "value": 13896},
    {"name": "Range", "value": 1594},
    {"name": "StringUtil", "value": 4130},
    {"name": "Sum", "value": 791},
    {"name": "Variable", "value": 1124},
    {"name": "Variance", "value": 1876},
    {"name": "Xor", "value": 1101}
   ]
  }
 ]
}


var bleed = 100,
    width = 960,
    height = 960;

var pack = d3.layout.pack()
    .sort(null)
    .size([width, height + bleed * 2])
    .padding(2);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + -bleed + ")");

  var data = pack.nodes(json)
//        .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; })
  ;
  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
      });

  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; });

  node.filter(function(d) { return !d.children; })
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .append("text")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .attr("dy", function(d) {
        // Cheat and calculate text length here
        d.ctl = 2 * d.r / Math.max(this.getComputedTextLength(), 24);
        return ".35em";
      });
   node.selectAll(".label")
    .attr("transform", d => "scale(" + d.ctl + "," + d.ctl + ")");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Order is important in describing transformations. There are two ways to look at them.

Consider the following sequence of transformations:

```
translate(40, 20) rotate(30) scale(1, 0.5)
```

If you read the transformations in the order they are written - left to right, and downwards in the DOM tree, you are transforming **coordinate systems**. Only after the final coordinate system has been established, the content is drawn into it:

[image: left to right: coordinate transformation]

Each transformation establishes the next coordinate system by transforming the current one.

But you can also read the transformations as transformation of the **content**. But then, you need to read from right to left, and up in the DOM tree:

[image]

This way, each transformation happens in the base coordinate system.